# Tomboy Notes is not starting

Tags: tomboy

My Tomboy Notes is not starting. As soon as I start it, it gets closed. This problem started when I added a task in Tasque and the task importer plugin was enabled in Tomboy Notes and then just happened to open my Tomboy Notes and it crashed.

Now I am using Gnote from few days, but I'm not satisfied. I want Tomboy back. What must I do in order to get Tomboy working again? Tell me how to reset it and as I have all the backups of my notes. Even removing it and reinstalling it will do for me. Tell me the procedure.

Comment: Have you try reinstall tomboy ?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a note in your default note directory that has a wrong format and tomboy is crashing when it tries to process it.

By default, on Ubuntu, your tomboy note directory is located at:

```
~/.local/share/tomboy
```

Since you already have a backup of your notes, move the notes to a temporary directory such as:

```
$ mkdir ~/.local/share/tomboy.store
$ mv ~/.local/share/tomboy/* ~/.local/share/tomboy.store/
```

After this, you will have verification that tomboy is crashing because it's having a problem with an ill formated note.  It shouldn't crash now, but should open up with no notes.

Now systematically move note from the store directory to the real directory.  When you move the problem note tomboy will start to crash again.  When you learn the problem note, you can  eliminate that note and have a working tomboy.

You can copy your notes back 10 at a tome (or any number) by:

```
$ mv `ls ~/.local/share/tomboy.store/*note | head -10` ~/.local/share/tomboy/
```

You may have to quit tomboy and restart it between blocks to see if it still crashes, or to help verify where the culprit note lies.

By the way, tomboy's notes are identified by the *.note extension.

> *Also, please note.  There is a bug with in Tomboy in that it will be confused with the timestamp of the note if you don't quit tomboy
>   between the moves (or copying of notes).  It will change the timestamp
>   of the note to the current time if you don't quit.  Quiting then
>   bringing in the new notes will preserve the correct timestamp.*